# laravel How to display items of one category on the relationship between item and category tables

Tags: php, laravel

I asked this question before but didnt get any answer,hope you have the solution.
As I have 2 tables, items and categories so every item has one category and one category can have many items.
my problem is when using groupby function but it shows one item for every category

**item model:**

```
 class Item extends Model
{
 protected $table="items";
protected $fillable= 
['item_title','category_id','item_price','item_details','item_image'];
protected $primaryKey='item_id';
public $timestamps=false;

public function categories()
{
$this->hasOne('App\category','category_id','category_id');
}
}
```

**category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
protected $table="categories";
protected $fillable=['category_name'];
protected $primaryKey='category_id';
public $timestamps=false;

  public function items()
  {
    $this->hasMany('App\items','category_id','category_id');
  }
  }
```

**Controller**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function getItems()
{
$items = Item::groupBy('category_id')->get();   
return view('home',compact('items'));
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
 @foreach($items as $indexKey => $item)
<div class="MenuPage_contentArea">
<div class="Category_root" id="one">
<div class="Category_categoryHeader">

<div><h2 class="Category_name">{{$item->item_category}}</h2></div>
<div class="Category_description"></div>
</div>

  <div class="Category_itemsContainer">
  <div class="Category_itemContainer">
  <button class="Item_root Button_root">
  <div class="Item_image" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('images/' . $item->item_image) }}');"></div>

<div class="Item_itemContent">
<div class="Item_topSection">
<span class="Item_name">{{$item->item_title}}</span>

<span class="Item_price">${{$item->item_price}}</span></div>
<div class="Item_description">{{$item->item_details}}</div>
</div>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping at SQL level, but if you want all of the items in a category grouped in a Collection, then use `groupBy` method from `Collection`. Use `all()`
 method to get a collection of all items, then use `groupBy()` method to group the `items` by `category_id`:

**HOME CONTROLLER**

class HomeController extends Controller

```
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        $items = Item::all()->groupBy('category_id');   
        return view('home',compact('items'));
    }
}
```

Access in your blade File as:

```
@foreach($items as $category_id => $categoryItems)
   Category ID: {{ $category_id }} <br>
   @foreach($categoryItems as $item)
     <!-- Display Item Details Here -->
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps you. :)

Comment: the problem when display using foreach, the sort of div can't be changed due to the css

Comment: What do you mean "the sort of div" ? I think your problem was grouping the items, not your css or html.